# How to fix 'Call was not successful' facebook marketing api error in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

**[Summarize the problem]**

I've followed a process of facebook marketing api docs, 
but I failed to connect facebook marketing api to my python program.
Response Message is 'Call was not successful'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwOAP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdGc3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH8UD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w84IT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM1YE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fMDV.png)

**[Provide background and tell us what you've already tried]**

Hi. 
I'm a data analyst of my company. 
I'm trying to connect facebook marketing api to my python program.
Version of Python is 3.7

I want to load daily marketing campaign cost of my company from facebook-ads.
I've succeeded to connect googleads api to my python program(called PDP),
but I failed to connect facebook marketing api to PDP.

First, I've search and followed the process of facebook marketing api docs.
-https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk?fbclid=IwAR26VDtM_hCRQqoZwrdlzy-nne8QZwN_j6oWxqDfxTtrUcELssFNTn_MRrM

-in this docs, 'Bootstrapping' part doesn't work.

-I think I put right app id, app secret, access_token.

-Please check below images and let me know If I something lost.

**[code]**

> import sys
>
> sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages')
>
> sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/facebook_business-3.0.0-py2.7.egg-info')
>
> from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
>
> from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
>
> my_app_id = '*******'
>
> my_app_secret = '*******'
>
> my_access_token = '*******'
>
> FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)
>
> my_account = AdAccount('act_<*******>')
>
> campaigns = my_account.get_campaigns()
>
> print(campaigns)

**[Describe expected and actual result]**

I guess if the code works, It should be printed the list of campaigns.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to solve problem.

**[code]**

> my_account = AdAccount('act_<*******>')
>
> ---> my_account = AdAccount('act_*******')

'<>' must be removed.

Refer to above way if somebody have same problem like me.